# show the final look of a text file that contains control characters

Tags: logging, cron, control-characters

I have a cronjob that runs a program whose output is redirected to a text file. During its execution, the program is showing a progression intended for the command line, with a final summary.

My problem is that the progression is continuously updating in the same line, using `\r` characters. Thus the redirected output weights ~450kB for a final look of a single page of text in the terminal, and is only readable through a `cat` that can replay the succession of codes. Any edition or display of the file shows a a second line of 446984 characters...

Is there a mean to store the "snapshot" of the final display of that file? I cannot find correct terms to search.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because cron to not create terminal when it run a task. For me the wise solution is to try to suppress (if it's possible) this progress bar. For example

```
wget -q ....
curl -s ...
```